# Create unique ID in rails 4 with Angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails 4 with angular. I am updating my site from a pure rails site and have created the back-end and populated the database. The ID's for the model "Droplets" began at 10, since the first nine were deleted from the dumped database I moved over. Now when it creates new Droplets, rails has begun adding them to the beginning (i.e. 1,2,3,4 etc). That was okay but now we've come to 10, instead of adding them to the next unique space, it is ignoring that 10 is already in the database and then violating the uniqueness constraint and the the POST request is failing.

Note: I have also changed the name of the model. How can I get rails to set ID's correctly again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to do this through Postgresql itself. (Call me old fashion :)

```
ALTER sequence your_table_id_seq restart 11;
```

where your_table is the table name

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the Postgres database sequence. It needed to be reset so that the id's for each table were set to the last one found. This was done in the rails console using:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!('table_name')
```

where you replace "table_name" with the name of the table you want to change the sequence for.